# How to increase size of Wither boss by using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a map and in it a Wither boss that is bigger and more challenging.  Is this possible using commands?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the scale of a mob in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition using commands.

---

However, you *can* create a behavior pack that will allow you to modify the scale, health and many other aspects of any mobs available in the vanilla packs using JSON data:

```
...
"minecraft:entity": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:wither",
      ...
    },

    "components": {
      ...
      "minecraft:experience_reward": {
        "on_death": "50"
      },
      ...
      "minecraft:boss": {
        "should_darken_sky": true,
        "hud_range": 55
      },
      "minecraft:damage_sensor": {
        ...
      },
      "minecraft:health": {
        "value": 600,
        "max": 600
      },
      ...
```

I have [a tutorial](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195199/how-can-i-create-a-minecraft-bedrock-edition-add-on) over on [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions) that could get you started with creating your first add-on (which includes a behavior pack). Additionally, if you experience issues creating a behavior pack, I'd recommend asking any related questions on Game Development SE as they're currently considered as off-topic here.

---

<sub>***Note**: This answer is accurate as of version 1.17.11.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible currently with the nbt tags we have right now, because with slimes and magma cubes you can do {Size:100} but other mobs are out of luck. You could use a resource pack with a model to make the wither appear bigger but the hitboxes would be the same unless you used a datapack to change the hitboxes

Comment: The author specified that their edition is Bedrock, not Java. As such I must point out that the syntax you provided won't work in BE, and data packs are limited to JE. Their equivalent in BE is an add-on comprised of a resource and behavior pack.